# How do I make a salah siran?

Tags: salat, reading-quran

I want to ask a simple but important question i am new to salah and i want to ask how to do the salah siran i speak so low or speak without moving my tongue?Does siran means all the speech in the salah to be so or only 9irat el koran?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between *jahran* and *sirran* is in the recitation of Quran. In *jahran* you recite Quran normally in a speaking volume, on the other hand in *sirran* you are silent. In most schools of thought reciting in *sirran* means that you go through the motion of *mouthing* the words of the Quran (move your tongue and lips) but without emitting a sound.